# Does the Car Mechanic Simulator 2015 contain DLC in Humble Bundle

Tags: humble-bundle, car-mechanic-simulator-2015

Car Mechanic simulator 2015 is in the latest Humble Tycoon Bundle. How can I tell if the game contains dlc? Usually Humble Bundle games contain all dlc, but is there a way to know before purchasing or activating the game?

Comment: If it doesn't say it comes with any DLC then I wouldn't assume it comes with any DLC. For example I can guarantee you that Train Simulator 2016, also included in the bundle, doesn't come with any of it's CDN $6,403.94 of DLC, let alone all of it. On the other hand, another game in the bundle, Democracy 3 Collector's Edition, does list the DLC it comes with.

Comment: It lists it? I noticed with some games that the DLC is included without it being listed. That is why I am asking

Comment: I don't think I've gotten any DLC from a Humble Bundle that wasn't explicitly listed, or included in the specifically named product being sold. For example when I bought a bundle that included "Batman: Arkham Asylum GOTY" that game included all the DLC because the GOTY edition includes all the DLC. But when I bought another bundle that included "Crusader Kings II", I got none of the DLC for that game.

Comment: I may be mistaken then. I will double check in the afternoon cause i just got to work

Comment: this question is about a time limited sale bundle and not an actual game

Comment: Yes it is. Is it not permitted? We have the humble bundle tag so i thought it was ok

Comment: I don't see why we should close humble bundle questions while we even have a tag for it.